# Pylons FormEncode with an array of form elements

Tags: python, pylons, formencode, htmlfill

I have a Pylons app and am using FormEncode and HtmlFill to handle my forms. I have an array of text fields in my template (Mako)

```
  <tr>
    <td>Yardage</td>
    <td>${h.text('yardage[]', maxlength=3, size=3)}</td>
    <td>${h.text('yardage[]', maxlength=3, size=3)}</td>
    <td>${h.text('yardage[]', maxlength=3, size=3)}</td>
    <td>${h.text('yardage[]', maxlength=3, size=3)}</td>
    <td>${h.text('yardage[]', maxlength=3, size=3)}</td>
    <td>${h.text('yardage[]', maxlength=3, size=3)}</td>
    <td>${h.text('yardage[]', maxlength=3, size=3)}</td>
    <td>${h.text('yardage[]', maxlength=3, size=3)}</td>
    <td>${h.text('yardage[]', maxlength=3, size=3)}</td>
  </tr>
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to validate these fields.
Here is the relevant entry from my Schema

`yardage = formencode.ForEach(formencode.validators.Int())`

I'm trying to validate that each of these fields is an Int.
However, no validation occurs for these fields.

**UPDATE**
As requested here is the code for the action of this controller. I know it was working as I can validate other form fields.

```
    def submit(self):
        schema = CourseForm()
        try:
            c.form_result = schema.to_python(dict(request.params))
        except formencode.Invalid, error:
            c.form_result = error.value
            c.form_errors = error.error_dict or {}
            c.heading = 'Add a course'
            html = render('/derived/course/add.html')
            return htmlfill.render(
                html,
                defaults = c.form_result,
                errors = c.form_errors 
                )
        else:
            h.redirect_to(controler='course', action='view')
```

**UPDATE**
It was suggested on IRC that I change the name of the elements from `yardage[]` to `yardage`
No result. They should all be ints but putting in f into one of the elements doesn't cause it to be invalid. As I said before, I am able to validate other form fields. Below is my entire schema.

```
import formencode

class CourseForm(formencode.Schema):
    allow_extra_fields = True
    filter_extra_fields = True
    name = formencode.validators.NotEmpty(messages={'empty': 'Name must not be empty'})
    par = formencode.ForEach(formencode.validators.Int())
    yardage = formencode.ForEach(formencode.validators.Int())
```

Comment: Could you share some more code, not least the controller code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out what I wanted to do wasn't quite right.

**Template**:

```
<tr>
  <td>Yardage</td>
  % for hole in range(9):
  <td>${h.text('hole-%s.yardage'%(hole), maxlength=3, size=3)}</td>
  % endfor
</tr>
```

(Should have made it in a loop to begin with.) You'll notice that the name of the first element will become `hole-1.yardage`. I will then use `FormEncode.variabledecode` to turn this into a dictionary. This is done in the

**Schema**:

```
import formencode

class HoleSchema(formencode.Schema):
    allow_extra_fields = False
    yardage = formencode.validators.Int(not_empty=True)
    par = formencode.validators.Int(not_empty=True)

class CourseForm(formencode.Schema):
    allow_extra_fields = True
    filter_extra_fields = True
    name = formencode.validators.NotEmpty(messages={'empty': 'Name must not be empty'})
    hole = formencode.ForEach(HoleSchema())
```

The HoleSchema will validate that `hole-#.par` and `hole-#.yardage` are both ints and are not empty. `formencode.ForEach` allows me to apply `HoleSchema` to the dictionary that I get from passing `variable_decode=True` to the `@validate` decorator.

Here is the `submit` action from my

**Controller**:

```
@validate(schema=CourseForm(), form='add', post_only=False, on_get=True, 
          auto_error_formatter=custom_formatter,
          variable_decode=True)
def submit(self):
    # Do whatever here.
    return 'Submitted!'
```

Using the `@validate` decorator allows for a much cleaner way to validate and fill in the forms. The `variable_decode=True` is very important or the dictionary will not be properly created.

Answer (score 1):

```
c.form_result = schema.to_python(request.params) - (without dict)
```

It seems to works fine.